# Explicit Formula for the Pseudo Inverses of a Family of Matrices Related to Calculating Certain Vertex Weights

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

Trying to identify canonical vertex weights for complete weighted graphs, I investigated the Ansatz, that the sum over the weights of all edges that are adjacent to same vertex, should equal the sum of the corresponding edgeweights.
In the symmetric case that Ansatz yields a non-singular square-matrix, whereas in the asymmetric case the resulting matrix is rank-deficient and one has to resort to pseudo inverses to obtain canonical vertex weights in that case.

Let $\mathcal{I}_n$ denote the $n\times n$ unit matrix and $\mathcal{J}_n$ the $n\times n$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$, then the matrices are
$$\mathcal{J}_n-\mathcal{I}_n+(n-1)\mathcal{I}_n$$ in the symmetric case and 
$$\begin{bmatrix} (n-1)\mathcal{I}_ n& \mathcal{J}_n-\mathcal{I}_n
\\\mathcal{J}_n-\mathcal{I}_n& (n-1)\mathcal{I}_ n\end{bmatrix}$$
in the asymmetric case, where the rank is $2n-1$

> **Question:**
>
> what are the values $a_{ij}$ of the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A^+$ of $$\begin{bmatrix} (n-1)\mathcal{I}_ n& \mathcal{J}_n-\mathcal{I}_n
> \\ \mathcal{J}_n-\mathcal{I}_n& (n-1)\mathcal{I}_ n\end{bmatrix}$$

in the asymmetric case one can formally distinguish between the weights of source-vertices and target-vertices of directed edges, which explains the doubling of the matrix-dimension, but it doesn't explain the incurred rank deficiency.